# Angular 5x - Send value from one component to another without child/parent relationship

Tags: angular5

The components don't have a parent/child relationship. That is, The first component doesn't have the second component's tag nested in it. It **doesn't** look like this:

```
<app-parent>
  <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

It's like this:

```
<app-root>
  <app-componentOne></app-componentOne>
  <app-componentTwo></app-componentTwo>
</app-root>
```

The first component has an unordered list `<ul>`. When I click one of the items `<li>`, I want the other component to show info about the clicked item.

I'm not looking for a code solution at this point (unless you want) I just want a concept I can learn about to create my own code.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

I ended up using `BehaviorSubject` RxJS message service to pass an object to the receiving component. Thanks to this YouTube video: [Sharing Data between Components in Angular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM), (Option #4).

I consider this solved, but if you'd like to add more, feel free.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of people have this problem.  So did I.  I want to be able to share data throughout my app without necessarily passing a bunch of data through middleware components.  I ended up using **reactive data stores** (using RxJs) to provide data streams to components.  These can be loaded from anything - an API call, or some local data.

For example, here is a pattern for a lazy-loading data store -

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerStore {

  // for lazy-loading
  initialized = false;

  // prefer a ReplaySubject with a buffer of 1
  private subject = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(private customerStore: CustomerStore) {

  }

  // expose as an observable stream
  getCustomer(): Observable<Customer> {

    // asynchronously loads the data on the first subscription to the store
    if (!this.initialized) {
      this.initialized = true;
      this.customerService.retrieveCustomer().subscribe((customer) => {
        this.subject.next(customer);
      });
    }

    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

For more information, check out http://blog.ippon.tech/reactive-data-using-angular-and-rxjs/

I'm also the author of the article.  Feel free to ask me any questions you might have in the comments of this StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the most underrated features of Angular5: `Services`. As much as `BehaviorSubject` can very well make this work, `Services` are both easier and cleaner to maintain. This is how you do it:

1. Create a `Service`.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
  sharedVariable: number = 1;

  constructor() { }

}
```

2. Inject it to the components that need the value/data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DemoService } from '../demo.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: DemoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.service.sharedVariable)
  }
}
```

Once you initialize the service in the `constructor`, you can reference it with `this` and its respective functions or variables.

[**Stackblitz demo here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-service)

Hope this helps!